# Adjusting UIImageView size and location based on the size of image fetched from service

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview

In my iOS7 app I have view just like profile page in any social networking site. I have a profile image in top left corner. I am fetching the image from service url and loading it to a `UIImageview`.

My problem is, I have to increase the size of this image view when the size of the image from service is big. And also i have to adjust other `UILabel`s beside this image view. I am using this code to get the size of image from url:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
CGSize size = img.size;
```

Comment: Ok, so how did you try changing the size and locations? Are you using auto-layout? What went wrong?

Comment: You could just set the contentMode of the imageView. `[self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];` that will make the image fit into the Image view you have.

Comment: @Wain, the image was stretched according to my UIImageview size. But i am getting different dimensions of images from the service. Some times service returns an image with square dimensions and some other times Rectangular dimensions. If rectangle then image gets compressed.

Comment: set the dimensions of your `imageView` the same as that of the `image` obtained from service.

Comment: Good Question. I am also facing the same problem.waiting for good answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `initWithData:cache:` method on UIImage class, is this category thing?

Anyway you can make UIImageView dimension to fit content UIImage by `[imageView sizeToFit]`.
If you want to adjust scale, use `[UIImage imageWithData:data scale:scale]`.

```
NSString *path = @"http://www.example.com/example@x2.png"
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data scale:2.0];
_imageView.image = img;
[_imageView sizeToFit];
```